# Characters sorting algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

**Input:  BDCAbaxz**

**OUTPUT: AaBbCDxz**

My solution is straight forward and ugly:

1. Sort the input with quick sort, then we get "ABCDabxz"
2. Alloc a temp array with the same size as the original one, then take the appropriate element from two sub-array(ptr1-->A, ptr2--->a)
3. Copy the temp array back to the original one

Any ***faster*** algorithm on this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Define a comparator for `qsort` that gives you the ordering you want in the first place (so rather than using `AB...YZab...yz` as the sort order, have it enforce `AaBb...YyZz`).

Comment: @Paul: `stricmp` sorts strings, not characters.  And it considers `'A'` and `'a'` as identical, which wouldn't give the OP the desired behaviour.

Comment: Oh yes - sorry - haven't woken up properly yet today... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If the input is long ( >> 255) you could make a counting sort.

```
char chars[256]; zeroed
while( *input)  // zero termination
    chars[*input++]++;
```

And extract it like

```
int pos = 0;
for(int i = 'A'; i<= 'Z'; i++)
{
    while( chars[i]-- ) 
        output(pos++] = (char)i;
    while( chars[i+'a'-'A']-- )
        output(pos++] = (char)i+'a'-'A';
}
```

O(N)